# Printing from a for loop with separators between each element but not at the end

Tags: python

How can I make sure that there is nothing at the end of the last print statement instead of "-"?

```
for i in range(0, 4,):
    print(i, end="-")
print()
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i, end="-")
```

Comment: use `sep` instead and keep `end` empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deadshot mentioned above, you should use `sep`.

Instead of

```py
for i in range(0, 4,):
    print(i, end="-")
print()
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i, end="-"
```

Try:

```py
print( *range(0, 4), sep='-' )
print( *range(0, 10, 2), sep='-')
```

Comment: That will surely work, but it would be better to give the author an explanation of what you are doing, since they are just starting with Python programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `join` method of strings to get your desired output (you need to transform the numbers to strings):

```py
print("-".join(str(i) for i in range(0, 4)))
print("-".join(str(i) for i in range(0, 10, 2)))
```

Alternatively you can use the `sep` argument of the `print` function and unpack the `range`:

```py
print(*range(0, 4), sep="-")
print(*range(0, 10, 2), sep="-")
```

Unpacking `range(x, y)` will have the same result as if you were passing multiple arguments to `print`. When you do so, the `print` function will join those inputs, by default it would join with a space but with the `sep` argument you can override the string used for joining

Comment: Both methods are probably too complex for a beginner. Instead of using `map()` a generator expression could be a little bit more accessible: `(str(item) for item in range(0, 4))`

Comment: You are right, list comprehensions are way more readable. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(0, 4,):
    print(i, sep="-")
print()
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i, sep="-")
```

Comment: This is exactly his code... Please provide an answer

Comment: read properly "end" needs to be changed with "sep" @MatteoZanoni

Comment: Including a bit of explanation in your answer can help make it clearer for people reading your answer what changes have been made so that they can learn and apply your solution to their use-case.

Comment: Also this will print each number on a separate line and the `sep` keyword is useless since you are only passing one argument to `print`.